# Typescript get type, that type guard function checks

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typeguards

I have a type guard function for type `User`. How do I extract the type, that this function "guards"? Using `ReturnType<typeof isUser>` obviously does not work since the return type of the function is `boolean`, not `User`.

```js
type User = {
  username: string
}

function isUser(value: unknown): value is User {
  return value !== null && typeof value === "object" && "username" in value;
}

type GuardType<T> = ...

// something like this?
type GuardTypeOfUserGuard = GuardType<typeof isUser>; // should be `User`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) on a similarly-shaped [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) type:

```
type GuardType<T> = 
  T extends (x: any, ...rest: any) => x is infer U ? U : never;
```

By "similarly-shaped" I mean that this will only match such functions where the first argument is the one guarded.  Anyway, you can check that it works:

```
type GuardTypeOfUserGuard = GuardType<typeof isUser>; 
// type GuardTypeOfUserGuard = User
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnICumUIcAthAFzLphSgDmuAvrrjISAmMAPYhkwdBmgAKAG5wANoWpEQAaxB8A7iACUNKbJTC0JHPmRQIYQqWQ65yAIQBee8hCFp05ADIPyMAE8ADhB8MFYyNo5OAER8AEYAVhA8kZ7ekcTQZJTJoKG6ANys7H6ByADihHBQACYAKgEQADw1AHzITjXIEAAekCBV6MhiXTRwIL4ANMgAdDOmdCNjGm2tXUIDoDBYqMgA-GjINCAQEtAFuAD057R8lGAAFkzI0sCKKPfCO7jFKOWVtfUAeRgoigv2qbTKFWqdUCDW+wTWIOaeWQl1odz4riqyBiKAABiC8Rcrt9IX8YRAgSCwdinCCgA)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know you could infer type guards. Thanks a lot